# Redirect user if they are logged in

Tags: redirect

This below script works great and redirects logged-out users to login page if they try to access the my-account page

```php
// Redirect account page to login page if user is logged out
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
    
      if ( is_user_logged_in() || ! is_page() ) return;
    
      $logged_in_restricted = array( 5156, 000 ); // all your restricted pages if user is logged out
    
      if ( in_array( get_queried_object_id(), $logged_out_restricted ) ) {
        wp_redirect( site_url( '/login' ) );  // page user redirected to if restriction met
        exit();
      }
    
});
```

How can I utilize the same script logic but target logged-in users instead of logged-out as an additional script? For example now I want to redirect logged-in users to the “my-account” page if they attempt to go to login/register pages. Here's an example:

```php
// Redirect login and register page to account page if user is logged In 
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
    
      if ( is_user_logged_out() || ! is_page() ) return;
    
      $logged_in_restricted = array( 3156, 4532 ); // all your restricted pages if user is logged In
    
      if ( in_array( get_queried_object_id(), $logged_in_restricted ) ) {
        wp_redirect( site_url( '/my-account' ) );  // page user redirected to if restriction met
        exit();
      }
    
});
```

I understand `is_user_logged_out` is not a thing. What can I use to accomplish this?

Comment: `if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )`

Answer (score 0):

#### Method 1

You could use [`login_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_redirect/) filter to add login redirect url.

The filter pass 3 arguments

```
// refer to /wp-login.php
   /**
    * Filters the login redirect URL.
    *
    * @since 3.0.0
    *
    * @param string           $redirect_to           The redirect destination URL.
    * @param string           $requested_redirect_to The requested redirect destination URL passed as a parameter.
    * @param WP_User|WP_Error $user                  WP_User object if login was successful, WP_Error object otherwise.
    */
```

The following example just pass the url, you can pass also $user argument and redirect according to different users.

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'ws365094_logout_redirect_to', 10, 3 );
function ws365094_logout_redirect_to( $redirect_to_url, $requested_redirect_to, $user ) {
  // any additional logic

  return site_url( '/my-account' ); // just pass this url, after login, it will be redirected by WordPress original login routine
}
```

#### Method 2

If you have a custom login form, you may pass variable "redirect_to" because wp-login.php will check if there is any. If you redirect all to same url, this method is simpler than method 1.

```
  <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="somewhere_url" />
```

For your original logout method, you may also use [`logout_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/logout_redirect/) filter to add logout redirect url instead of `template_redirect` action. `template_redirect` is quite universal but more use cases in redirecting to specific template(template control). Just an additional notes for reference.

#### Sequence comparison between `template_redirect` and `login_redirect`

According to the loading sequence. By default, after login, WordPress redirect the user to a specific page in order to get the cookie working which I have answered [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/363102/wp-logout-url-redirects-to-confirmation-page-even-with-nonce/363186#363186) before.

`Login -> Redirect -> Template Redirect(canonical) which is normally done by redirect_canonical() if slug does not found, go to 404, if using /?p=111, check if permalink is in used, if so, direct to permalink structured url and so on`

If using `template_redirect`, it means the page is being handled in `template-loader.php`. It becomes

`Login -> Redirect -> Template Redirect(canonical) -> Custom Template Redirect`

Because it follows do_action( 'template_redirect' ) in template loader which will load multiple times in this case. One way to optimize the script is that using a higher priority for the custom `template_include` hook so that it check and redirect earlier functioning similar to Login Redirect.

Since reaching `template_redirect` is a bit late of loading time. So it is still not an ideal place to do a user login checking and redirect to somewhere which is not template related matters.

So, unless necessary such as doing rewrite, custom URL structure or custom template preparation. Using it in later time is not recommended. Also, if redirect is handling unskilfully, it might also affect the SEO ranking. That's based on the actual loading sequence, SEO optimisation point of view and personal experience.

Answer (score 0):

I was very happy with the above logic and just needed it slightly changed. Adding a `!` before `is_user_logged_in()` solved my issue completely and allowed me to do the logic in reverse.

```
/**********************************START*************************************
********** Redirect account page to login page if user is logged In *********
****************************************************************************/

add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {

  if ( ! is_user_logged_in() || ! is_page() ) return;

  $restricted = array( 4062, 4066 ); // all your restricted pages

  if ( in_array( get_queried_object_id(), $restricted ) ) {
    wp_redirect( site_url( '/account' ) ); 
    exit();
  }

});
```